# How to melt multiple number of columns which filled with date in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this table:

```
a   b   c   d    e    f   2019-08-06   2019-08-07   2019-08-08   g    h    i
1   2   3   4    5    6        7           8           9        10    11   12
```

Since I have 34 columns of the date, so I want to melt the date columns to be into one columns only. So there will be column like below in my table:

```
date          value
2019-08-06     7
2019-08-07     8
2019-08-08     9
```

what I have tried was:

```
a = df.columns.str.match("\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}")
cols = df.columns[a]
df.melt(id_vars = df.columns.difference(cols), var_name = "date", value_name = 'value')
```

But it didnt work, I got error when I  defined "cols" which said:

```
Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values
```

When I print[a], I got:

```
Index([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
         nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,
         nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,
         nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,
         nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,
         nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,
         nan,   nan, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
      dtype='object')
```

How can I fix this?

Thankyou.

Comment: Your date is 4 digits, then 2, then 2, not 2-2-2- like your regex

Comment: It looks more like the dates are actually `datetime` type. So `str.match` returns `nan` not `False`.

Comment: ah I see, so how should I change my script?

Comment: `id_vars = [col for col in df.columns if isinstance(col, str)]`?